# post two array in one input box and separate it after post, php

Tags: php, html

I have two arrays and I post the arrays in one input;

```
<input name='sistem[]' type='hidden' value='$items[$count]|$staff[$z]' />  
   // $count and $z are index
```

After post, how do I extract them into two separate arrays again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$items=new Array();
$staff=new Array();
foreach($_POST['sistem'] as $item){
    $itemSplit=explode('|',$item);
    $items[]=$itemSplit[0];
    $staff[]=$itemSplit[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things: If it's actually just a hidden input field, why don't you make it into two fields in your code? Or, even better, store it in the session so that there is no chance a malevolent user can't change the value on the field on submitting the request to the web server?

But to answer the question directly:

`$parts = explode('|', $_REQUEST['sistem'][0]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST['sistem'] as $key => $value)
{
   $tmp = explode("|", $value);
   $items[$key] = $tmp[0];
   $staff[$key] = $tmp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its the best solution, but one solution could be to prefix your values